# Check if an image exists in an Anchor tag before adding one

Tags: jquery, image, selector

just wondering if you could help me on this one,
I have anchor tags for PDF docs on a page. Some have a pdf icon associated

```
<li>
   <a class="pdf" href="/link_to_pdf_1.pdf" target="_blank"> Title of PDF 1
     <img alt="Adobe PDF document" src="/link_to_pdf_icon/pdf-icon.png">
   </a>
</li>
```

Some do not.

```
<li>
  <a class="pdf" href="/link_to_pdf_2.pdf" target="_blank">Title of PDF 2 </a>
</li>
```

I have some jQuery code that appends a pdf icon for links that have a class .pdf

`$('a.pdf').append('<img src="/link_to_pdf_icon/pdf-icon.png" alt="Adobe PDF document"/>');`

This is adding a second icon for the first link. How should check if an image already exists before adding another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [:has](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/tactP/

```
$('a.pdf').not(':has(img)').append('<img src="/link_to_pdf_icon/pdf-icon.png" alt="Adobe PDF document"/>');
```

Comment: Thanks roasted, I'm gonna give it to you as you did get there first.

Answer (score 6):

Here you go

```
$('a.pdf:not(:has(img))').append('<img src="/link_to_pdf_icon/pdf-icon.png" alt="Adobe PDF document"/>');
```

Comment: Simple and best . +1 for that

Comment: Wow that was quick :) Let me check it out.

Comment: Isn't :contains only for text as specified in doc: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Sorry, you guys are right. My mistake. Corrected but please upvote @roasted too as he came up with the right answer first.

Comment: I gave you an up vote Bruno, but I gave the correct answer to roasted as he did get there first. Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: @roasted You're welcome :-) RonanC - It's right that it goes to roasted